# Finding usages of string == operator in a large codebase

Tags: c#

I've had a request to look into the feasibility of replacing all of the string `==` operator usages in a reasonably large C# codebase with `String.Equals()` method calls that explicitly specify case-sensitivity.

Haven't had much luck figuring out a way to identify all the occurrences in the codebase, though.

- Searching for "==" obviously finds countless instances of types other than strings being compared.
- There doesn't seem to be a StyleCop rule to find this.
- Nor a ReSharper rule.
- As a last resort I tried loading the assemblies into JustDecompile and finding all usages of `System.String.op_Equality` but that doesn't seem to pick up usages inside of LINQ expressions such as `.Where(x => x.StringField == stringField)`

So I'm a little stumped and wondered if anyone had any ideas on how to search these pesky comparisons out?

Comment: I would be very interested in hearing why you were requested to look into such a thing. That seems like an awfully unproductive use of your time..... Is this a "standards document adherence" thing?

Comment: Why `searching for " == " finds countless instances of types other than strings being compared`? What are those other `types`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal What if they are string variables and not magic strings?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I think something like "int", "object" and so on...

Comment: @Matten: "int" is string and not Int32.

Comment: Rejecting pointless requirements is part of a programmer's work. I suggest you ask "why need I do this".

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal i meant Int32 and object.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: yeah, pretty much. I'm certainly not going to claim that it is a productive use of my time. :-) @Nikhil: ints, mainly, searching for "==" will find all the `intValue == 1` along with string comparisons. @Danny: don't worry, I'm pushing back! But getting a clear picture of how many string comparisons there are is part of that process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Resharper to find all the usages. Here's what works for me:

1. Right click on the string type anywhere in your code. Click *Go to Declaration*.
2. Resharper will open string.cs from the .NET framework
3. Scroll down to `operator ==` and right click, select *Find Usages*

It takes a bit of time but you'll get a nice list of usages, ordered in a tree view.
I tried this with Resharper 6.1 in VS2010.

**UPDATE**

There is a simpler way to do this:

1. Select `==` in a string comparison
2. Right click on the selection and choose *Find Usages Advanced*
3. In the dialog under find check only 'Usages' and set scope to 'Solution' to filter out any references in other libs.

Comment: Very nice.  Beats my answer by miles :)

Comment: Good suggestion. However, when I try this in VS2012RC and R#7, and right-click on `operator ==` the _Find Usages_ option is disabled. Actually, _Find Usages_ seem to be disabled for all methods in the _String.cs_ metadata file. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I couldn't get this to work. "Find Usages" (assume that's what you meant, I don't have a "Show Usages" menu item) scans through all the code files in my solution, but then in its results, it just gives me 1432 usages in referenced libraries, basically festooned throughout the `System.` namespace. Nothing from my code.

Comment: You're right about the menu option, it's called *Find Usages*. I've updated my answer. I've also added a simpler way to find the usages.

Comment: Absolute champion! Tried your updated method and it works perfectly! Narrows thousands of "==" search results down to hundreds of actual string comparisons, and since you can view the actual line of code in Resharper's tree view, it's easy to skip over the `if stringVar == null` checks and just look at `if thisString == thatString`.

Answer (score 0):

My advise would be to write a very basic and specific code parser which transverses through each scope in your system, recording all `string`/`String` variable declarations and detecting any `==` comparisons using those variables.

Anyone with a deeper knowledge on code parsing is welcome to comment.  I'm sure there are some classes/tools out there that one could use.